# Removing "eliminated by erasure" warning in Scala

Tags: scala, erasure

I have a simple Scala function that generates a Json file from a `Map[String, Any]`.

```
  def mapToString(map:Map[String, Any]) : String = {
    def interpret(value:Any)  = {
      value match {
        case value if (value.isInstanceOf[String]) => "\"" + value.asInstanceOf[String] + "\""
        case value if (value.isInstanceOf[Double]) => value.asInstanceOf[Double]
        case value if (value.isInstanceOf[Int]) => value.asInstanceOf[Int]
        case value if (value.isInstanceOf[Seq[Int]]) => value.asInstanceOf[Seq[Int]].toString.replace("List(", "[").replace(")","]")
        case _ => throw new RuntimeException(s"Not supported type ${value}")
      }
    }
    val string:StringBuilder = new StringBuilder("{\n")
    map.toList.zipWithIndex foreach {
      case ((key, value), index) => {
        string.append(s"""  "${key}": ${interpret(value)}""")
        if (index != map.size - 1) string.append(",\n") else string.append("\n")
      }
    }
    string.append("}\n")
    string.toString
  }
```

This code works fine, but it emits a warning message in the compilation.

```
Warning:(202, 53) non-variable type argument Int in type Seq[Int] (the underlying of Seq[Int]) 
is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
        case value if (value.isInstanceOf[Seq[Int]]) => 
value.asInstanceOf[Seq[Int]].toString.replace("List(", "[").replace(")","]")
                                                ^
```

The line `case value if (value.isInstanceOf[Seq[Int]])` causes the warning, and I tried `case value @unchecked if (value.isInstanceOf[Seq[Int]])` to removed the warning, but it does not work.

How to remove the warning?

Comment: Please take a look at `mkString`, seems like your function can be simplified a lot. `map.toList.map { case (k, v) => s"""  "$k": ${interpret(v)}""" }.mkString("{\n", ",\n", "\n}\n")`

Comment: @Łukasz: It's great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't really care about the component type (and it seems you do not, as all you do is stringify it):

```
case value if (value.isInstanceOf[Seq[_]]) => 
    value.asInstanceOf[Seq[_]].toString.replace("List(", "[").replace(")","]")
```

Come to think of it, you should be able to call `toString` on anything anyway:

```
case value if (value.isInstanceOf[Seq[_]]) => 
    value.toString.replace("List(", "[").replace(")","]")
```

but instead of `toString` followed by messing with the String consider `Seq#mkString`

```
value.mkString("[", ",", "]")
```

Finally, that pattern `isInstanceOf`/`asInstanceOf` can be replaced by a match (in all the cases)

```
case value: Int => value    // it's an Int already now, no cast needed 
case value: Seq[_] => value.mkString("[", ",", "]")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following,

```
case value: String => ???
case value: Double => ???
case value: Int => ???
case value: Seq[Int] @unchecked => ???
```

or as @Thilo mentioned

```
case value: Seq[_] =>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the better code that generates no warning message (with the hints from Thilo & Łukasz).

```
  def mapToString(map:Map[String, Any]) : String = {
    def interpret(value:Any)  = {
      value match {
        case value:String => "\"" + value + "\""
        case value:Double => value
        case value:Int => value
        case value:Seq[_] => value.mkString("[",",","]")
        case _ => throw new RuntimeException(s"Not supported type ${value}")
      }
    }
    map.toList.map { case (k, v) => s"""  "$k": ${interpret(v)}""" }.mkString("{\n", ",\n", "\n}\n")
  }
```